# is it good practice to use iframe to implement header/navbar?

Tags: html

is it good practice to use iframe to implement header/navbar?

my website is basically 5 thousand pages but all static html (not using any content manager, php, etc.).

am in the process to add a navbar at the top of each page. e.g. tabs, or crumbs, or any sort of header with js menu. (the exact design not decided yet)

my question is, is it good practice to use a iframe for this? (so, instead have same text repeated in all 5 thousand pages, each will just have a short iframe pointing to a header file)

am aware that one should reduce http request for speed, but this is ok with me. Any other problems i might have with this? SEO or any tech issue?

Comment: Five thousand pages? Could I ask what this is for? On this level, I would consider moving to a dynamic solution. I don't want to know what would you do with this when a little change is needed.

Comment: it's basically tutorial stuff and blog i worked over past 15 years. xahlee.org basically i code in emacs and upload daily (rsync) This is why i want to use iframe for header so any change i can change just 1 file instead of find/replace by script on all pages. Switching to content manager is currently not desired (time, design etc constraints)

Comment: if at all you can, consider server side includes as an option, so instead of an iframe, you will add an #include line in each page.  it is also possible to get the webserver to output fixed html before and after actual content.  this may or may not be possible or convenient.  also, if there is a single starting page from where all these pages are linked and each page links to other pages,  you may consider showing the pages themselves in a iframe which would mean you create only one extra starting html page and other pages remain untouched.

Comment: You're concerned about the time it would take to implement a dynamic solution? I suspect that you'd *save* far more time than you'd lose by implementing a dynamic solution. Five thousand static pages? ...that terrifies me. @_@

Comment: [server side includes] @BinaryNights If my header file include all js scripts, if I include header on all file, then it reload, means every time bundle of script refresh as header reload ! ?

Answer (score 6):

Using iframes to display parts of the same document is not good practice. Consider the document as a whole and that should give you the answer. Or consider that there are devices who don't do well when encountering iframes. And speaking of SEO is funny. Documents without header of footer (hence no internal links), or with just the navigation pointing to other iframe wrappers don't do well.

If your goal is to avoid using a dynamic language, how about going for SSI ([Server Side Includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes))?

Comment: any example of device that don't work well with iframe? Also, am not sure what problem iframe has exactly. Seems to me iframe is picking up more use as mechanism for widgets...

server side include is interesting, but i want to avoid it if i can. (it means i have to deal with server settings, which often isn't in my control, and some of my html projects are downloadable standalone books.)

Comment: Not all mobile browsers know how to deal with iframes, and anyway, the SEO loss is enough reason to avoid them. Usually you don't have to change any settings to use SSIs. Have you actually tried and failed?

Comment: if, my header file include all scripts, if I show-up/include header on all file, then it reload, means every time bundle of script refresh as header reload ! ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to move to a fully dynamic solution. Consider this simple 3 step solution, assuming you are on Apache.

1. add a file named .htaccess into your root directory with the text `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html` in it. This makes apache parse any php code in a html file.
2. Put `<?php include('header.html'); ?>` at the top of every page.
3. Create a single **header.html** page which will then show up on every other html page.

Comment: my header file include all scripts, if I show-up/include header on all file, then it reload, means every time bundle of script refresh as header reload ! ?

Comment: @Shahid, yes, everytime your page loads, the included header file is "reloaded". But that's no different than if the code from your header file was in your main file.

Comment: OK! But I want to stop the header file to "RELOAD" ? but include !

Comment: @Shahid You can't do that with include. you will need to look into more advanced techniques.

Answer (score 0):

No please, dont use iframes.
I'm afraid your using a bad aproach.

You need to move to something a little more advanced (nothing really complicated).
Just a couple of scenarios:

1. Not much of a programmer -> try
   Joomla (http://www.joomla.org/)
   Really easy, just grab a nice
   template and create articles (silly
   CMS) in order to build those mills.
   of pages.
2. Like JAVA? Right -> try making a
   webapp with includes or tiles

Comment: my header file include all scripts, if I include header on all file, then it reload, means every time bundle of script refresh as header reload ! ?