# Pitfalls Of Wrapping Menu In iFrame?

Tags: html, css, iframe

### Pitfalls Of Wrapping Menu In iFrame?

To save some legwork in the future, changing content on one page versus every page, I was thinking of turning reoccurring sections of my page into "modules". Basically, I made a page with my menu on it (`menu.html`) and ported it in to my `index.html` via an iFrame `<iframe src="menu.html" width="100%">`

Will this work the way I'm thinking it will? Will I lose a lot of speed with this? Are there any obvious reasons why I shouldn't do this? Will the cons outway the pros?

***Note:** I plan on putting all modules on one page to reduce Requests, and then just preposition the content in the iFrame (like a Sprite Sheet)

**jsFiddle:**

- menu.html - http://jsfiddle.net/z6awcy6g/
- index.html - http://jsfiddle.net/3r9ukgvz/1/

Comment: I found a similar thread after posting.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556880/is-it-good-practice-to-use-iframe-to-implement-header-navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question specifically, the main "pitfall" is that the menu simply won't work. When you click on a link in an iframe it opens the link in the frame (unless you specify target="top").

If you have PHP available (basically every host supports it), you can use includes instead. This is the correct way to implement this.